# When the series $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^a$ is convergent depending on $a\in\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When the series  $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^a$ is convergent depending on $a\in\Bbb R$?

For $a=0 $ the series is divergent.

Else:

$\sqrt[n]{n}-1=\frac{e^{1/n\ln n}-1}{1/n \ln n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\ln n\sim\frac{\ln n}{n}$

So, $\sqrt[n]{n}-1$ is asymptotically similar to $\frac{\ln n}{n}$, and $(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^a$ will converge when $(\frac{\ln n}{n})^a$ converges. But I don't know how to finish it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a>1$, compare to $\frac1{n^{1+(a-1)/2}}$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^a\Big/\frac1{n^{1+(a-1)/2}}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^an}{n^{a/2-1/2}}$$
Since $a>1$, $\frac a2-\frac12>0$, hence the limit equals $0$. The series converges.
For $a\le 1$, compare to $\frac1n$:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^a\Big/\frac1{n}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^an}{n^{a-1}}=\infty$$
Even if $a<0$, the limit still diverges to infinity. Hence the series diverges.

Comment: $$\sqrt[n]{n}-1\le  \frac{e}{e-1} \frac{\log(n)}{n}$$

Comment: @MarkViola Could you please explain it more explicitly

Answer (score 1):

> In a comment, the OP asked "Could you please explain it more explicitly," which referenced the comment I left "$\sqrt[n]{n}-1\le \frac{e}{e-1} \frac{\log(n)}{n}$".  To address the OP's request, we now proceed.

---

Using $e^x<\frac1{1-x}$ for $x<1$ and $\min\left(1-\frac1n\log(n)\right)=1-e^{-1}  $ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{n}-1 &=e^{\frac1n\log(n)}-1\\\\
&\le \frac{\frac1n\log(n)}{1-\frac1n\log(n)}\\\\
&\le \frac{e}{e-1} \frac{\log(n)}{n}\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you were going to use the formula to point out the mistake in my solution. Sorry for not expressing my thought correctly.